# Openshift online v3 - build Red Hat image (is Docker EE needed?)

Tags: image, docker, openshift, rhel7

I want to build a custom image to use on openshift online v3. Based on rhel 7. On the install page on docker.com it becomes clear that you will need Docker Enterprise Edition to install docker on rhel 7. Is it possible through a tool or workaround to build a docker image based on rhel7, without buying Docker Enterprise Edition?

Comment: What OpenShift cluster are you using? You can run docker type build in OpenShift itself. The question is whether the cluster you are using allows that. That said, you still don't need Docker Enterprise Version. If you are building on RHEL, it already has a docker package you can install from operating system packages. Have you tried running ``yum -y install docker``.

Comment: If you are on RHEL and using a subscription, you can find details in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html-single/getting_started_with_containers/index

Comment: openshift online, i edited my question. My goal is to build a image FROM rhscl/s2i-base-rhel7

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thank you, I enabled the repos: # subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-rpms
# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms . Then I installed docker and i could pull the repo i wanted. Thank you!

Comment: If you are actually using RHEL and have subscriptions then you can possibly do it, but am not sure how you stand in respect of taking the image based on RHEL and using it outside of your RHEL systems with the subscriptions. As far as I know you aren't for example then meant to go push your custom image based on the RHEL one up to Docker Hub. So you would want at least to push it direct to registry in OpenShift. You could always use the CentOS version of that same base image, then you wouldn't have any issues.

Comment: I want to use it in Openshift Online

Comment: That is probably fine. You will just want to login to the internal image registry of OpenShift and push it direct into it. To use as an S2I builder you can then select from the web console, you will need to add appropriate labels to the image stream created.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, you might want to add your first comment as the answer, i.e. No Docker EE required, just install the regular `docker` package from RHEL repos, and you're fine. See also https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3092401

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton added the answer, bulding new red hat images for openshift worked like a charm after your help.

Answer (score 0):

No Docker EE required, just install the regular docker package from RHEL repos, and you're fine. See also access.redhat.com/solutions/3092401

I enabled the repos:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-rpms 
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```

Then I installed docker with yum install docker and i could use the red hat images. Thank you @GrahamDumpleton!